# Drawing curved line arrow on a bar graph using affine transformation

Tags: java, jfreechart, affinetransform

I am trying to draw a curved Line arrow on a stacked bar graph.I have been able to draw the curved line and arrow.But i am not able to connect the arrow to the end of the curved line.I am using affine transformation to draw the curved line.The below link describes the curved line and arrow that i have been able to draw http://i58.tinypic.com/2m422hy.png.Can anyone guide me as to how to connect the arrow to the end of the curved line.

Here is the code

package Stack;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author OSPL-B4
 */
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.jfree.chart.annotations.CategoryAnnotation;

import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAnchor;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.event.AnnotationChangeListener;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Plot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.io.SerialUtilities;
import org.jfree.ui.RectangleEdge;
import org.jfree.util.ObjectUtilities;
import org.jfree.util.PaintUtilities;
```

//import java.awt.Font;

```
/**
* A line annotation that can be placed on a
* {@link org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot}.
*/
public class CategoryLineAnnotation_demo1 implements CategoryAnnotation,
                                               Cloneable, Serializable {

    /** The category for the start of the line. */
    private Comparable category1;

    /** The value for the start of the line. */
    private double value1;

    /** The category for the end of the line. */
    private Comparable category2;

    /** The value for the end of the line. */
    private double value2;
     private final int ARR_SIZE = 4;
    /** The line color. */
    private transient Paint paint = Color.black;

    /** The line stroke. */
    private transient Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(1.0f);

    /**
     * Creates a new annotation that draws a line between (category1, value1)
     * and (category2, value2).
     *
     * @param category1  the category (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     * @param value1  the value.
     * @param category2  the category (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     * @param value2  the value.
     */
    public CategoryLineAnnotation_demo1(Comparable category1, double value1,
                                  Comparable category2, double value2,
                                  Paint paint, Stroke stroke) {
        if (category1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'category1' argument.");   
        }
        if (category2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'category2' argument.");   
        }
        if (paint == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'paint' argument.");   
        }
        if (stroke == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'stroke' argument.");   
        }
        this.category1 = category1;

        System.out.println("First Category value is "+category1);
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.category2 = category2;

         System.out.println("Second Category value is "+category2);
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.paint = paint;
        this.stroke = stroke;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the category for the start of the line.
     *
     * @return The category for the start of the line (never <code>null</code>).
     */
    public Comparable getCategory1() {
        return this.category1;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the category for the start of the line.
     *
     * @param category  the category (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     */
    public void setCategory1(Comparable category) {
        if (category == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'category' argument.");   
        }
        this.category1 = category;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the y-value for the start of the line.
     *
     * @return The y-value for the start of the line.
     */
    public double getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the y-value for the start of the line.
     *
     * @param value  the value.
     */
    public void setValue1(double value) {
        this.value1 = value;   
    }

    /**
     * Returns the category for the end of the line.
     *
     * @return The category for the end of the line (never <code>null</code>).
     */
    public Comparable getCategory2() {
        return this.category2;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the category for the end of the line.
     *
     * @param category  the category (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     */
    public void setCategory2(Comparable category) {
        if (category == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'category' argument.");   
        }
        this.category2 = category;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the y-value for the end of the line.
     *
     * @return The y-value for the end of the line.
     */
    public double getValue2() {
        return this.value2;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the y-value for the end of the line.
     *
     * @param value  the value.
     */
    public void setValue2(double value) {
        this.value2 = value;   
    }

    /**
     * Returns the paint used to draw the connecting line.
     *
     * @return The paint (never <code>null</code>).
     */
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return this.paint;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the paint used to draw the connecting line.
     *
     * @param paint  the paint (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     */
    public void setPaint(Paint paint) {
        if (paint == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'paint' argument.");
        }
        this.paint = paint;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the stroke used to draw the connecting line.
     *
     * @return The stroke (never <code>null</code>).
     */
    public Stroke getStroke() {

       // System.out.println("In Stacked bar Stroke is "+getStroke());
        return this.stroke;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the stroke used to draw the connecting line.
     *
     * @param stroke  the stroke (<code>null</code> not permitted).
     */
    public void setStroke(Stroke stroke) {
        if (stroke == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null 'stroke' argument.");
        }
        this.stroke = stroke;
    }

    /**
     * Draws the annotation.
     *
     * @param g2  the graphics device.
     * @param plot  the plot.
     * @param dataArea  the data area.
     * @param domainAxis  the domain axis.
     * @param rangeAxis  the range axis.
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2, CategoryPlot plot, Rectangle2D dataArea,
                     CategoryAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis) {

        CategoryDataset dataset = plot.getDataset();
        int catIndex1 = dataset.getColumnIndex(this.category1);
        int catIndex2 = dataset.getColumnIndex(this.category2);

        int catCount = dataset.getColumnCount();

        double lineX1 = 0.0f;
        double lineY1 = 0.0f;
        double lineX2 = 0.0f;
        double lineY2 = 0.0f;
        PlotOrientation orientation = plot.getOrientation();
        RectangleEdge domainEdge = Plot.resolveDomainAxisLocation(
            plot.getDomainAxisLocation(), orientation);
        RectangleEdge rangeEdge = Plot.resolveRangeAxisLocation(
            plot.getRangeAxisLocation(), orientation);

        if (orientation == PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL) {
            lineY1 = domainAxis.getCategoryJava2DCoordinate(
                CategoryAnchor.MIDDLE, catIndex1, catCount, dataArea,
                domainEdge);
            lineX1 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(this.value1, dataArea, rangeEdge);
            lineY2 = domainAxis.getCategoryJava2DCoordinate(
                CategoryAnchor.MIDDLE, catIndex2, catCount, dataArea,
                domainEdge);
            lineX2 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(this.value2, dataArea, rangeEdge);
        }
        else if (orientation == PlotOrientation.VERTICAL) {
            lineX1 = domainAxis.getCategoryJava2DCoordinate(
                CategoryAnchor.MIDDLE, catIndex1, catCount, dataArea,
                domainEdge);
            lineY1 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(this.value1, dataArea, rangeEdge);
            lineX2 = domainAxis.getCategoryJava2DCoordinate(
                CategoryAnchor.MIDDLE, catIndex2, catCount, dataArea,
                domainEdge);
            lineY2 = rangeAxis.valueToJava2D(this.value2, dataArea, rangeEdge);
        }
        g2.setPaint(this.paint);
        g2.setStroke(this.stroke);

        drawArrow(g2,(int) lineX1, (int) lineY1, (int) lineX2, (int) lineY2);
    }

     void drawArrow(Graphics g1, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g1.create();


            double dx = x2 - x1, dy = y2 - y1;

            System.out.println("Value of DX "+dx);
            System.out.println("Value of DY "+dy);
            double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

            System.out.println("Getting angle "+angle);
            int len = (int) Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
            at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
            g.transform(at);

            System.out.println("Affine transform X co-ordinate value is "+at.getScaleX());

           System.out.println("Affine transform Y co-ordinate value is "+at.getScaleY());
         float center1=(x1+x2)/2-40;
         float center2= (y1+y2)/2-40;     
         QuadCurve2D q=new QuadCurve2D.Float(0,0,center1,center2,x2,y2);


         g.draw(q);

         g.setColor(Color.RED);

         System.out.println("Length of arrow is "+len); 

         System.out.println("Get Start point 2D "+q.getP1());
         System.out.println("Get End  point 2D "+q.getP2());

          g.fillPolygon(new int[] {len, len-ARR_SIZE, len-ARR_SIZE-10, len-60},
                      new int[] {0, -ARR_SIZE, ARR_SIZE-20, 5}, 4);


        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            for (int x = 15; x < 200; x += 16)
                drawArrow(g, x, x, x, 150);
            drawArrow(g, 30, 300, 300, 190);
        }



    /**
     * Tests this object for equality with another.
     *
     * @param obj  the object (<code>null</code> permitted).
     *
     * @return <code>true</code> or <code>false</code>.
     */
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof CategoryLineAnnotation_demo1)) {
            return false;
        }
        CategoryLineAnnotation_demo1 that = (CategoryLineAnnotation_demo1) obj;
        if (!this.category1.equals(that.getCategory1())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.value1 != that.getValue1()) {
            return false;   
        }
        if (!this.category2.equals(that.getCategory2())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.value2 != that.getValue2()) {
            return false;   
        }
        if (!PaintUtilities.equal(this.paint, that.paint)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!ObjectUtilities.equal(this.stroke, that.stroke)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a hash code for this instance.
     *
     * @return A hash code.
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO: this needs work
        return this.category1.hashCode() + this.category2.hashCode();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a clone of the annotation.
     *
     * @return A clone.
     *
     * @throws CloneNotSupportedException  this class will not throw this
     *         exception, but subclasses (if any) might.
     */
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();   
    }

    /**
     * Provides serialization support.
     *
     * @param stream  the output stream.
     *
     * @throws IOException if there is an I/O error.
     */
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException {
        stream.defaultWriteObject();
        SerialUtilities.writePaint(this.paint, stream);
        SerialUtilities.writeStroke(this.stroke, stream);
    }

    /**
     * Provides serialization support.
     *
     * @param stream  the input stream.
     *
     * @throws IOException  if there is an I/O error.
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException  if there is a classpath problem.
     */
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        this.paint = SerialUtilities.readPaint(stream);
        this.stroke = SerialUtilities.readStroke(stream);
    }

@Override
public void addChangeListener(AnnotationChangeListener al) {

}

@Override
public void removeChangeListener(AnnotationChangeListener al) {


}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the arrow head based on the last line segment (which might already be transformed using an AffineTransform)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ArrowPainter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new ArrowPaintPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(panel);
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class ArrowPaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener
{
    private Point2D startPoint = null;
    private Point2D endPoint = null;

    ArrowPaintPanel()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

        if (startPoint == null)
        {
            startPoint = new Point(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        }
        if (endPoint == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(startPoint, endPoint);
        Shape arrowHead = createArrowHead(line, 30, 20);
        g.draw(line);
        g.fill(arrowHead);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        endPoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        endPoint = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }

    private static Shape createArrowHead(Line2D line, double length, double width)
    {
        Point2D p0 = line.getP1();
        Point2D p1 = line.getP2();
        double x0 = p0.getX();
        double y0 = p0.getY();
        double x1 = p1.getX();
        double y1 = p1.getY();
        double dx = x1 - x0;
        double dy = y1 - y0;
        double invLength = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        double dirX = dx * invLength;
        double dirY = dy * invLength;
        double ax = x1 - length * dirX;
        double ay = y1 - length * dirY;
        double offsetX = width * -dirY * 0.5;
        double offsetY = width * dirX * 0.5;
        double c0x = ax + offsetX;
        double c0y = ay + offsetY;
        double c1x = ax - offsetX;
        double c1y = ay - offsetY;
        Path2D arrowHead = new Path2D.Double();
        arrowHead.moveTo(x1, y1);
        arrowHead.lineTo(c0x, c0y);
        arrowHead.lineTo(c1x, c1y);
        arrowHead.closePath();
        return arrowHead;
    }


}
```

EDIT: Update for the above EDIT and the comments: That's a lot of code, but still nothing that can be tested easily. What happens when you replace your line

```
drawArrow(g2,(int) lineX1, (int) lineY1, (int) lineX2, (int) lineY2);
```

with

```
g.fill(createArrowHead(new Line2D.Double(lineX1, lineY1, lineX2, lineY2), 30, 20));
```

?

Comment: i am able to draw an arrow on a straight line.I want to draw an arraw for the curved line.Can you please help me with that.

Comment: You should probably add the code (that is, where you create and draw the curved line) into your original question

Comment: -I have pasted the code into the original question.Can you guide as to how i can rotate the arrow so that it fits the curved line,i mean it is connected to the curved line.

Comment: Added an EDIT, although the code is not in a form that is easy to test and understand...